# Add new object to given table using Oracle SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wish to write a script in *PL SQL* that asks for a table from the user, then repeatedly pops up the columns of that table so that the user can input the values thus adding a new row. Any ideas?
EDIT: by popping up the columns I mean showing a dialog window where the user can input.

By showing dialog I mean e.g. `var:= &input_this_stuff;`

Comment: You'll need an interactive script or application framework (e.g. [Apex](https://apex.oracle.com/en/)) capable of popping up windows. PL/SQL runs in the database server and is not interactive.

Comment: I meant only the `myTable := &give_table_name` command for example.

Comment: Then you'll need a SQL*Plus script that generates and runs a script that defines variable for every column in the specified table. Still no PL/SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll check that out.